# Grep for keyword over multiple directories and move found files

Tags: linux, bash, loops, grep, find

I have a folder with multiple folders and 66gb of files. (.doc/.docx/.xls/.xlsx/.msg. etc..)

I need a loop command that will search recursively through the entire directory structure for a key word in the files body &/or header and then move the found files to a separate location.

I have tried this command and it works on a single folder, but when I add the -r to the grep command it grabs an entire folder because one of the files contains a keyword search match.

```
for file in *
do
  if grep -rq 'Pro*' "$file"
  then
    sudo mv "$file" /home/pdog/Downloads/testmv/
  fi
done
```

I have been looking at ways of doing this for the last 24 hours and I simply can't work out why the entire folders are being moved also?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for file in `grep -rl ...`
```

The `-l` (`--files-with-matches`) will only print filenames, so you should end up with the collection of all files that match, exactly as you want.

EDIT: To deal with spaces, try this:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
FILES=`grep -rl ...`
IFS="$OLDIFS"
for file in $FILES
do
  ...
done
```

Comment: So just to clarify: am I putting the `grep -fl ...` in place of the * in the first line "for file in? cause if this is the case then I get the following error: 

   grep: l: No such file or directory

Comment: @user2566508: Gaah, typo. Should be `-rl`.

Comment: I think I'm having an issue with white space now
the following error appears

grep: Untitled: No such file or directory
grep: Document: No such file or directory
grep: (copy): No such file or directory

Comment: Yeah, spaces in file names are annoying. Try putting `IFS=` (setting `IFS` to nothing) on the line before `for`. It might change the rest of your code's behaviour; if so, save it before in another variable, and restore it after. I'll edit it in the answer...

Comment: Ok so I tried that - but still not getting the result's I'm looking for. I thought about taking a step back and starting with generating a list of files to be moved into a txt file. Which I've been able to do. I appreciate that this is different to what I originally asked - so I'm happy to persist with this question.

There is also a likeyhood that the same file name will exist in multiple files, how do I get it to copy the files to a new location maintaining the same folder structure.

Alternative to this - I'd be happy to simply have it rm -f the files it matches and be done with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -irl "key word" * | xargs -n1 -I{} mv {} /home/pdog/Downloads/testmv/
```

Comment: Thx -  xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option. Before running this I need to make sure that the folder structure is maintained - as there are 100's of 1000's of files and I can't be sure there aren't duplicate names.

Comment: @Summo Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I was getting an error telling me to input -0 into the command line. So I added the -0 switch and ran the command. I looked at the folder and some files moved over but then it just sat there - I'm presuming it stopped because it didn't move to the next folder.

Comment: @Summo Looks like your files have spaces. Sorry about that, use the updated command.

Comment: xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

That's the error I get - so I added the -0, but it just sits and does nothing.... I put the -0 after the {}

I also get this error if I run it from the test folder where the files are actually located, mv: cannot stat ‘TEST/Doc1 Unclass test\nTEST/AnotherFolder/Sensitive - af\nTEST/AnotherFolder/Untitled Unclassified - af\nTEST/AnotherFolder/Unclassified - af\nTEST/Doc Unclas - test\nTEST/Hot Frog - test\n’: No such file or directory